# How to move resources from one site to another. Modx CMS

Tags: import, export, content-management-system, modx, modx-revolution

I have two websites running on Modx CMS. One of them is older and the other one is a newer version of the same website. I need a way to move all my resources from the old website to new. Or, probably, export all resources and then import them.

Comment: Please clarify which MODX versions do you use for both websites?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try **BobRay's MyComponent** https://github.com/BobRay/MyComponent

Change class_key to 'Article' and it will work fine. Also, check version compatibility.